# Is it safe to use Capital One Bank?

Tags: united-states, banking, savings-account

After the recent Capital One hack, is it safe to keep a savings account with Capital One ?

Answer (score 3):

I would say it's as safe as any other major bank. Many retailers have been hacked as well, so there's no way to be completely sure that your info won't get stolen without going "off the grid" completely.

If you're concerned about identity theft, then you can look into Identify Theft Insurance. It doesn't compensate you directly, but it helps monitor your credit activity to keep someone else from using your identity to take out a loan, for example, and some will help you deal with the hassle of dealing with a stolen identity, which is more of a convenience benefit than a monetary benefit.

Comment: Given the nature of identity theft, Identity Theft Insurance sounds like it could potentially make things *easier* for identity thieves.